# concourse: cf-resource sso login options

Tags: concourse, pcf

How to configure cf resource with sso options ? 
Is there any way that we can pass the passcode url to obtain the token through cf resource and pass it as an --sso-passcode for login?

```
- name: cf
  type: cf
  source:
    api: ((cloud_foundry_api))
    username: ((cloud_foundry_username))
    password: ((cloud_foundry_password))
    organization: ((cloud_foundry_organization))
    space: ((cloud_foundry_space))
```